# CodeIgniter, Facebook and Sessions. Getting lots of oAuth Access Token Errors

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I've been using CodeIgniter for a couple of years. I don't make things too complex, basically, I do this in my controller's constructor:

```
$conf = array ( 'appId' => 'MY APP ID', 'secret' => 'MY SECRET KEY');

$facebook = $this->load->library('facebook/facebook',$conf);
```

And then, to log the user in, I use the same method on the [example.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php) provided by facebook (get user ID, try catch making an API call). **Everything on my controller's constructor**.

In the couple of years of using this methodology, everything has worked ok, until now. Last week I coded an app writing basically the same code in every app I've done in the past, the problem is I'm getting A LOT of oAuth Access Token errors, to be precise, I'm getting a message saying that the access token has expired and I need a new one to query the facebook API.

So, I know I'm not giving much information about my code, but what I like to discuss is the methodology and not the code itself:

**How do you handle facebook login in your app?** Do you think the way I'm doing it is OK or I have to do it in a method and not in the constructor? Do I have to save the access token in the database so I can use the same access token when the user come back to the app?

It would be great if you have an example with codeigniter.

**Thank you very much in advance!**

P.s: I'm autoloading CI sessions library, using the [channel.php file with an expire date of a year](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) and using p3p headers so browsers do accept cookies. I really don't know what I'm missing.
P.s2:"I've read a lot of related questions here in stackoverflow, I've tried some advices I've read here, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 3.2.1 of the SDK contains a bug, which is fixed in the (yet untagged) 3.2.2 release. Replace your base_facebook.php file with the latest version on github at:

https://raw.github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/master/src/base_facebook.php

This commit:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/commit/ca9472b3312dab3fdcfbffb4e45eb091f582dcb7

references the fix of "trying to reuse spent auth tokens".

This drove me insane. It may well be that there was a loophole closed in the graph API that requires this updated code and there was never a bug... either way, it's fixed in the latest.

My codeigniter code:

```
$config['appId'] = '408995679168867';
$config['secret'] = 'secret';
$this->load->library('facebook', $config);
```

and then

```
$fbid = $this->facebook->getUser();
$this->fb_me = $this->facebook->api("/me");
```

should have the try/catch in there and etc, but i left it out for readibility.

Comment: I've been testing for a while and looks like everything is working ok right now. Thank you very much!